# Generating a txt file from attribute table, multiple shapefiles in a folder

Tags: python, arcmap

Edited for clarification. Thisis the process I currently use:
In ArcMap 10.6 I perform an intersect between 2 shapefiles, one is a drivetime area and one is a set of points in a geographical area. The intersect identifies which points lie within the drivetime area. I am not saving the result in the gdb but in a folder as a shapefile. ArcMap automatically adds this shapefile to the table of contents. I right click on the generated shapefile and select open attribute table. In the window that opens, I navigate to the column that I want "pat_id" then highlight it, then right click and select summarize. I change the output from a dbf to a text file then point it to a folder on my local machine, giving it a unique name. The pat_id field is a list of unique integers, it is the only column (field) that I need. I need to do this about 1400 times. I am a novice with python and model building, my attempts (which are many) have not resulted in an output that matches the process above. There is some baseline knowledge for model building that I have not acquired yet, and all the snippets I have tried normally lead to no output being generated. I am editing this question again to see if I can get help with a solution. Ideally I would like to build a scrip so that I can export the single field from each shapefile attribute table to a text file. I my be butchering the terms, but I do not know how to explain it another way.

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to finish your goal.

Comment: Welcome to [gis.se]. Please visit our [tour] to learn about our focused Q/A format. Please [edit] your post to limit to a single question. We appreciate any effort that you can do beforehand. For example, post a question just on the first task. How to automate it in python, but include what you have done and where you are stuck. Once you have completed that task, and are stuck with the second task, post another question.  This is the way this site works. In the meantime, I will close your question until it is edited.

Comment: I edited the question to focus on one part of the process that has me stumped

Comment: @Robert28791 when you say summarise - what do you want? Is that value duplicated and you just want a unique list of values that appear in that shapefile?  If you have any code you've been working on, it usually helps to post snippets out of it so we can see exactly what you're trying to do.

Comment: Can you add an example showing exactly what you want to do with each shapefile and how the output should look like. To get you started with a code attempt, google ListFeatureClasses or os.walk and da.SearchCursor. Which ArcMap version do you have?